# How to place Select input Html Table

Tags: jquery, html

I Place a select Dropdown in a table but when you click to dropdown none of the items can be selected.

```html
    <table id="tbl_matches" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>NHIS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Paracetamol</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Amoxy</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Nico</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Cefa</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Amo</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script>

    let sel = 
        '<select id="product_select">' +
            '<option>Para</option>' +
            '<option>Amozy</option>' +
            '<option>Chloro</option>' +
            '<option>Niph</option>' +
        '</select>'

    $('#tbl_matches tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

            $('#product_select').parents('td').html($('#product_select option:selected').text());
            curr = $(this).find('td');

            curr.eq(1).html(sel);

        } );

</script>
```

When I click to dropdown the options in the select cannot be selected. On single click of a table row it closes the dropdown automatically.

I have it the working code here

https://jsfiddle.net/addosmash/d3nL8jwk/1/

Comment: Your click event is bubbling up from the select to the row, and replacing the select that's already present in the row with a new one - which is why you can't select anything - it's replaced each time you try. `event.stopPropagation` will stop the event from bubbling up the DOM. https://jsfiddle.net/v9qa5jp1/

Comment: Thanks Mark but I realized I still cannot select an Item

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle link I provided in the comment? I also just updated it here to replace the select when a value is chosen, instead of when the next row is clicked: https://jsfiddle.net/x63r7a10/

Comment: Great it works fine **thank you @mark.hch**